# How to write sql nested queries with "not in" in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sql query that I want to convert to pyspark:

```sql
select * from Table_output where cct_id not in (select * from df_hr_excl)
```

Pseudo Code:

```
Table_output=Table_output.select(col("cct_id")).exceptAll(df_hr_excl.select("cct_id")) or 
col("cct_id").isin(df_hr_excl.select("cct_id"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlated subqueries in where clause with `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` can be written using left anti join :

```
Table_output = Table_output.join(df_hr_excl, ["cct_id"], "left_anti")
```

As per your comment, if you have a condition in your subquery then you can put it in the join condition. E.g.:

```
Table_output = Table_output.alias("a").join(df_hr_excl.alias("b"), (F.col("a.x") > F.col("b.y")) & (F.col("a.id") == F.col("b.id")), "left_anti")
```

Comment: Sorry @blackbishop somehow or somene deleted all the comments.If possible can u please rewrite the solution in the above answer.Would be much help!

Comment: @Alastair added to the answer ;)